# Why thread need to disable interrupts to implement lock?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, operating-system

I read everywhere that to implement a lock thread need hardware support - disable interrupts.

> No matter how we choose to implement locks, we must have some hardware
>   support. One possibility to implement locks is to disable interrupts,

Comment: It is a *possibility*.  That never gets used because processors [have this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap).

Comment: It's not even a possibility on any multicore CPU because.. well multiple cores.

Comment: @HansPassant Spin-lock using CAS is not always optimal. See MCS lock for one example. Under contention, MCS should be better.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing was the mechanism used for simple locking in older OSes that operated on single processor systems. Even then, complex locking (e.g., for a database) required a lot more.

Now, with multiprocessor systems, blocking interrupts all the processors at the same time would not help.

CPUs that support multi-processing have memory interlocked instructions.The olde VAX had an interlocked branch on bit set and set instruction and even a remove from queue interlocked instruction for heavy duty work. Such hardware support has been around for a long time.